# Return distinct list from a list of objects containing an array

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following object structure:

```
   public class Summary{
     public string[] Sources { get; set; }
     public string Label { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a query in which i am returning a `List<Summary>`

I am trying to create either a linq or lambda expression that will return a `List<string>` with distinct values of Sources.

I have tried this so far but not sure if its correct:

```
    var sources = Summaries.Select(x => x.Sources.Distinct().ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupBy to do that.See below code

```
Summary a= new Summary();
a.Label="T1";
a.Sources=new string[]{"abc","def","xyz","abc","ccc"};
            
var result=a.Sources.GroupBy(m=>m).Select(group=>group.First());
            
foreach(var item in result){
    Console.WriteLine(item);    
}
```

Output will be

```
abc
def
xyz
ccc
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What if it was in a List<Summary>?